# Overloading function where input has certain member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, enable-if

I'm attempting to overload a function depending on whether the passed in sequence container has `push_back` as a member function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::push_back)>, int> = 0>
void has_push_back(T p)
{
  std::cout << "Has push_back" << std::endl;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::push_back)>, int> = 0>
void has_push_back(T p)
{
  std::cout << "No push_back" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec = { 0 };
  std::array<int, 1> arr = { 0 };
  std::forward_list<int> f_list = { 0 };

  has_push_back(vec);
  has_push_back(arr);
  has_push_back(f_list);
  
  return 0;
}
```

This results in the following compiler error for each of the calls to has_push_back():

```
error C2672: 'has_push_back': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'void has_push_back(T)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
```

Expected result:

```
Has push_back
No push_back
No push_back
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [expression SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <forward_list>

void has_push_back(...)
{
  std::cout << "No push_back" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
auto has_push_back(T&& t) 
  -> decltype(t.push_back(t.front()), void()) 
  // ^^ expression SFINAE, only considered 
  // if the whole expression within decltype is valid
{
  std::cout << "Has push_back" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec = { 0 };
  std::array<int, 1> arr = { 0 };
  std::forward_list<int> f_list = { 0 };

  has_push_back(vec);
  has_push_back(arr);
  has_push_back(f_list);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Has push_back
No push_back
No push_back
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dbzafs1nY

`&T::push_back` may not be well formed when `push_back` is a template or overloaded. Instead, I check if a call with `t.front()` to `push_back` is valid or not. Of course this also requires the type to have a suitable `front` member.